# How to use a prior median in ggplot aesthetic in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, median

I am trying to calculate a median as one number, and then use that number as a value in the aesthetic of ggplot.

I first try to obtain the median as a value:

```
mean_delay_median <- nycflights13::flights %>% 
  group_by(dest) %>%
  summarise(mean_delay = mean(arr_delay, na.rm = TRUE)) %>% 
  median(mean_delay)
```

This yields the error message:

```
Error in median.default(., mean_delay) : need numeric data
```

How can I fix this?

Once I get this working, my second step would be to color a map based on values above and below this median "mean_delay_median", with something like this:

```
nycflights13::flights %>% 
  group_by(dest) %>%
  summarise(mean_delay = mean(arr_delay, na.rm = TRUE)) %>% 
  inner_join(nycflights13::airports, c('dest' = 'faa')) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(lon, lat, color=mean_delay>mean_delay_median)) +
  borders("state") +
  geom_point() +
  coord_quickmap()
```

In general, I seek guidance on using prior statistics in subsequent code.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you just miss the `summarise(median_all_delay = median(mean_delay, na.rm = TRUE))`

try this:

```
mean_delay_median <- nycflights13::flights %>% 
  group_by(dest) %>%
  summarise(mean_delay = mean(arr_delay, na.rm = TRUE)) %>% 
  summarise(median_all_delay = median(mean_delay, na.rm = TRUE)) %>% 
  unlist()

nycflights13::flights %>% 
  group_by(dest) %>%
  summarise(mean_delay = mean(arr_delay, na.rm = TRUE)) %>% 
  inner_join(nycflights13::airports, c('dest' = 'faa')) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(lon, lat, color=mean_delay>mean_delay_median)) +
  borders("state") +
  geom_point() +
  coord_quickmap()
```

output is:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should note that one destination(`dest`) has every `arr_delay` observation missing.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(nycflights13)

flights %>% 
  group_by(dest) %>% 
  filter(all(is.na(arr_delay))) %>% 
  select(dest, arr_delay)
#> # A tibble: 1 x 2
#> # Groups:   dest [1]
#>   dest  arr_delay
#>   <chr>     <dbl>
#> 1 LGA          NA
```

This leads to `NaN`, not zero.

```
mean(c(NA), na.rm = TRUE)
#> [1] NaN
```

In other words, you should add `na.rm = TRUE` again in `median` function.

```
flights %>% 
  group_by(dest) %>% 
  summarise(mean_delay = mean(arr_delay, na.rm = TRUE)) %>% 
  mutate(arrival = ifelse(mean_delay > median(mean_delay, na.rm = TRUE), "late", "okay")) %>% # na.rm option to median
  inner_join(airports, by = c("dest" = "faa")) %>% 
  ggplot() +
  aes(lon, lat, colour = arrival) +
  borders("state") +
  geom_point() +
  coord_quickmap()
```

[image]

Since mean value for `LGA` does not have any value, its label might become `NA`.

Comment: Thanks this approach works fine here, I just added filter(!is.na(mean_delay)) to drop the NA from the legend.